# How to add Hover Template over Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code, and would like to display x & y axis data when hovering over the points:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = ['25/02/2023 0:00', '25/02/2023 0:01', '25/02/2023 0:02', '25/02/2023 0:03', '25/02/2023 0:04', '25/02/2023 0:05', '25/02/2023 0:06', '25/02/2023 0:07', 
        '25/02/2023 0:08', '25/02/2023 0:09', '25/02/2023 0:10', '25/02/2023 0:11', '25/02/2023 0:12', '25/02/2023 0:13', '25/02/2023 0:14', '25/02/2023 0:15', 
        '25/02/2023 0:16', '25/02/2023 0:17', '25/02/2023 0:18', '25/02/2023 0:19', '25/02/2023 0:20', '25/02/2023 0:21', '25/02/2023 0:22', '25/02/2023 0:23', 
        '25/02/2023 0:24', '25/02/2023 0:25', '25/02/2023 0:26', '25/02/2023 0:27', '25/02/2023 0:28', '25/02/2023 0:29', '25/02/2023 0:30']

temp = ['0', '-21', '20', '30', '-40', '50', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', 
        '15', '16', '17', '-18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', 
        '29', '68']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)),
                  columns = ['ts', 'temp'])
df['temp']=df['temp'].astype(float)
df1 = df.reset_index()
df100 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df100['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df100['ts'])
df100['ts'] = df100['ts'].dt.strftime('%d-%m--%H:%M')

df100.plot.bar(x="ts", y="temp", rot=90, figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("temp")
plt.title('Temperature')
plt.show(block=True)
```

I would like to display time and temperature data while hovering please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable interactive hovering over the data points in a Matplotlib plot, you'd typically need an interactive backend and additional libraries. One popular choice is `plotly`, but in this solution, I'll guide you on how to use `mplcursors`, which is a utility for Matplotlib to provide interactivity.

Here's how you can modify your code:

1. First, you'll need to install `mplcursors`:

```py
pip install mplcursors
```

2. Then you have to modify your code to include `mplcursors` and display hover information:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors  # <--- Add this import

ts = [ ... ]  # your list remains unchanged

temp = [ ... ]  # your list remains unchanged

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)), columns=['ts', 'temp'])
df['temp'] = df['temp'].astype(float)
df1 = df.reset_index()
df100 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df100['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df100['ts'])
df100['ts'] = df100['ts'].dt.strftime('%d-%m--%H:%M')

ax = df100.plot.bar(x="ts", y="temp", rot=90, figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("temp")
plt.title('Temperature')

# Add interactivity with mplcursors
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)

plt.show(block=True)
```

Now, when you hover over the bars in your plot, a tooltip will display the x and y values (i.e., time and temperature).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have since modified as follows so the label doesn't stay on the screen even after mouse is pointed away from the plot:  mplcursors.cursor(ax, hover=mplcursors.HoverMode.Transient).

Answer (score 3):

To display time and temperature data when hovering over points in your bar graph, you can use the mplcursors library. This library allows you to add interactive data labels to your Matplotlib plots.

```
pip install mplcursors
```

Here is how you can modify your code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

ts = ['25/02/2023 0:00', '25/02/2023 0:01', '25/02/2023 0:02', '25/02/2023 0:03', '25/02/2023 0:04', '25/02/2023 0:05', '25/02/2023 0:06', '25/02/2023 0:07', 
        '25/02/2023 0:08', '25/02/2023 0:09', '25/02/2023 0:10', '25/02/2023 0:11', '25/02/2023 0:12', '25/02/2023 0:13', '25/02/2023 0:14', '25/02/2023 0:15', 
        '25/02/2023 0:16', '25/02/2023 0:17', '25/02/2023 0:18', '25/02/2023 0:19', '25/02/2023 0:20', '25/02/2023 0:21', '25/02/2023 0:22', '25/02/2023 0:23', 
        '25/02/2023 0:24', '25/02/2023 0:25', '25/02/2023 0:26', '25/02/2023 0:27', '25/02/2023 0:28', '25/02/2023 0:29', '25/02/2023 0:30']

temp = ['0', '-21', '20', '30', '-40', '50', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', 
        '15', '16', '17', '-18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', 
        '29', '68']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)),
                  columns=['ts', 'temp'])
df['temp'] = df['temp'].astype(float)
df1 = df.reset_index()
df100 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df100['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df100['ts'])
df100['ts'] = df100['ts'].dt.strftime('%d-%m--%H:%M')

# create the bar plot
ax = df100.plot.bar(x="ts", y="temp", rot=90, figsize=(12, 6))

# add interactive data using mplcursors
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(ax, hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(f"Time: {sel.target[0]}\nTemperature: {sel.target[1]:.2f}"))

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.title('Temperature')
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: HI Mishal, thank you, how do I include the timestamp to be displayed with the temperature as well please?

Comment: @Ashu you can modify the lambda function inside the cursor.connect method to include both the timestamp and temperature. 
Like this `cursor.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(f"Time: {sel.target[0]}\nTemperature: {sel.target[1]:.2f}"))`

Comment: Hi @Mishal, thanks for your help.  Just another thing, the time only displays seconds, can it display the hour and seconds ( if not the date) please?  Also I have added as follows so the seconds don't jump decimal places: (f"Time: {sel.target[0]:.0f}